# newInstance() is not displayed for XML file creation in java

Tags: java, xml

I had imported `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder`, `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory` for XML manipulation. While creating reference for document builderfactory, the `newinstance()` was not displayed. Anyone help me to fix it?

Syntax:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory
.newInstance();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "was not displayed"?

Comment: correct my words as "Not able to import newinstance() method into my program"